# React render method not working when referencing jsx file in html

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to reference a jsx file from my html, but the render function is not showing anything, and there aren't any errors in the console.

*Note - I changed the fb CDN links below as SO wouldn't allow them. The CDN links are not the issue.

My code looks like this:

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://f*b.me/react-0.14.6.js"></script>
    <script src="https://f*b.me/react-dom-0.14.6.js"></script>
    <script src="http://f*b.me/JSXTransformer-0.12.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div id="loggedin"></div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/script.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JSX**

```
var App = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return(
            <h1>Hello</h1>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('loggedin'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React uses `babel` to convert your jsx to js. So, add `babel` instead of `JSXTransformer` and save the file as `.js` not `.jsx`

Add this to your script

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-core@5.8.38/browser.min.js"></script>
```

[Reference](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html#starter-pack)

Comment: it should say `React uses` not `React not uses`, right?